# Cannot get SQL Server 2012 Transaction to rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions

```
SELECT *
FROM [Production].[Product]

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;
        UPDATE [Production].[Product]
        SET Color = 'Off White'

        SELECT *
        FROM [Production].[Product]

        SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS 'Transaction Count'

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
END CATCH;

SELECT *, @@TRANCOUNT AS 'Transaction Count'
FROM [Production].[Product]
```

I am not getting any errors but the changes are not rolling back like they are supposed to... any thoughts?

Comment: Since it's in a TRY block, it should only roll back if the TRY fails. If you have no errors, the expected outcome would be that the TRAN is not rolled back. Have you run this query without the TRY/CATCH?

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM [Production].[Product]

     BEGIN TRAN;
      UPDATE [Production].[Product]
      SET Color = 'Off White'
      SELECT *
      FROM [Production].[Product]
      SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS 'Transaction Count'
     COMMIT TRAN;
     ROLLBACK TRAN;


    SELECT *, @@TRANCOUNT AS 'Transaction Count'
    FROM [Production].[Product]'

Comment: Changes are still not rolled back

Comment: Sounds like you might have Autocommit Transactions turned on. It's the default for sql2012.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Production].[Product]

BEGIN TRAN;
SAVE TRAN Product1;
    UPDATE [Production].[Product]
    SET Color = 'Off White'
    SELECT *
    FROM [Production].[Product]
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS 'Transaction Count'
    ROLLBACK TRAN Product1;
COMMIT TRAN;




SELECT * 
FROM [Production].[Product]
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS 'Transaction Count'
```

This works as i needed it to, thought i would share the wealth!~

Edit 1: Forgot to include crucial changes to the code, I'm only human!